# yeoman EACCES: permission denied

Tags: linux, yeoman

Just installed `npm install -g yo generator-office` as on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/word-quickstart?tabs=visual-studio-code . Upon running yo, Getting the following:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/write-file-atomic/index.js:197
    throw err
    ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/amarshanand/Library/Preferences/insight-nodejs/insight-yo.json.4213605520'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
    at Function.writeFileSync [as sync] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/write-file-atomic/index.js:180:17)
    at Conf.set store [as store] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/conf/index.js:142:19)
    at new Conf (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/conf/index.js:44:14)
    at new Insight (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js:40:35)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js:46:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
```

Actually, the file `insight-yo.json.4213605520` doesnt even exist. What exists is `insight-yo.json` . Any idea what is wrong?

versions:

```
+ generator-office@1.1.14
+ yo@2.0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Was another permission issue. Resolved it by running

`sudo chown -R $USER /Users/amarshanand/Library/Preferences/insight-nodejs/`

Comment: Useful for Microsoft's 2017 tutorial, "Create a single-page web app with REST API backend." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/get-started-tutorial-fullstack-web-app#:~:text=Part%20I%3A%20Build%20a%20REST%20API%20backend%201,up%20your%20data%20model.%20...%20More%20items...%20